# How to create constructor for TYPES in postgresql similar to oracle

Tags: postgresql

I have a sample code to create TYPES in Oracle with constructor function. But when I am trying to create the same in postgresql, its is giving me error. Please find the oracle and postgres conversion.

Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL".database_dsc_t as object (
  version     number,

  do_sync_db   number,
  do_start_svc number,
  do_mod_local_svc number,

  want_ons_config number,

  db_number   number,
  cloud_name  varchar2(128),
  dbpool_name varchar2(128),
  region_name varchar2(128),
  shdgrp_name varchar2(128),
  shdgrp_id   number,
  num_inst    number,
  cpu_thld    number,
  disk_thld   number,
  do_force    number,
  chunks      number,
  service_list   service_dsc_list_t,
  region_list    region_list_t,
  gsm_list       gsm_list_t,

  ons_port  varchar2(256),
  scan_name varchar2(256),
  hostname  varchar2(256),
  db_type   char,

  sharding_type number,
  deploy_as number,
  status number,
  shardspace_name varchar2(128),
  shardspace_id number,
  repl_type number,
  MINNUM NUMBER,
  MAXNUM NUMBER,
  DBLPWD VARCHAR2(64),
  DBLEP VARCHAR2(256),
  GWM_INTDBNUM NUMBER,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION database_dsc_t (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY database_dsc_t,
                                      dbnum NUMBER)
                                     RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

/*----------------------------------------------*/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL".database_dsc_t AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION database_dsc_t (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY database_dsc_t,
                                      dbnum NUMBER )
                                     RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.db_number := dbnum;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
```

Postgres Conversion:

```
CREATE TYPE "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL".database_dsc_t as (
  version     double precision,
  do_sync_db   double precision,
  do_start_svc double precision,
  do_mod_local_svc double precision,
  want_ons_config double precision,
  db_number   double precision,
  cloud_name  varchar(128),
  dbpool_name varchar(128),
  region_name varchar(128),
  shdgrp_name varchar(128),
  shdgrp_id   double precision,
  num_inst    double precision,
  cpu_thld    double precision,
  disk_thld   double precision,
  do_force    double precision,
  chunks      double precision,
  service_list   service_dsc_list_t,
  region_list    region_list_t,
  gsm_list       gsm_list_t,
  ons_port  varchar(256),
  scan_name varchar(256),
  hostname  varchar(256),
  db_type   char,
  sharding_type double precision,
  deploy_as double precision,
  status double precision,
  shardspace_name varchar(128),
  shardspace_id double precision,
  repl_type double precision,
  MINNUM DOUBLE PRECISION,
  MAXNUM DOUBLE PRECISION,
  DBLPWD VARCHAR(64),
  DBLEP VARCHAR(256),
  GWM_INTDBNUM DOUBLE PRECISION,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION database_dsc_t (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY database_dsc_t,
                                      dbnum DOUBLE PRECISION)
                                     RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)

/*------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TYPE BODY "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL".database_dsc_t AS
  CONSTRUCTOR 
CREATE FUNCTION database_dsc_t (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY database_dsc_t,
                                      dbnum INT )
                                     RETURNS SELF AS
 DECLARE $$ RESULT IS
  BEGIN

    SELF.db_number := dbnum;
    RETURN;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
END;
```

When I try to create the TYPE without Function in postgresql, I am able to create the TYPE.

Comment: Types don't have member functions in Postgres. Which part [of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) made you think they do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, We are given this as part of the requirements while migrating the complete database from oracle to PostgreSQL.